# MapViewOfFile returns different addresses with same handle

Tags: c++, ipc

I'm trying to implement IPC for a school assignment by sharing memory.
I made a class called `SharedMemoryBuffer` to deal with creating file mappings and views.

My `Init()` function looks like this:

```
BYTE * SharedMemoryBuffer::Init(const wchar_t * name, size_t bufferSize)
{

    FileMapHandle = OpenFileMapping(
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
        FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
        name);               // name of mapping object

    if (FileMapHandle == NULL)
    {
        FileMapHandle =
            CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
                NULL,
                PAGE_READWRITE,
                0,
                bufferSize,
                name);

        pBuf = (BYTE*)MapViewOfFile(FileMapHandle, // handle to map object
            FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
            0,
            0,
            bufferSize);
    }
    else
    {
        pBuf = (BYTE*)MapViewOfFile(
            FileMapHandle,
            FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
            0,
            0,
            bufferSize
        );
    }
    return this->GetBuffer();
}
```

Essentially, I pass it a name and size and it tries to open a mapping with this name. If it fails, it creates it instead.

I call it like so
`this->ringBuffer.Init(widestr.c_str(), buffSize);`

After this is done (I call Init 4 times for 2 buffers, from the same process) I print out the addresses of the buffers (`pBuf` from `Init()`) but theyre all different addresses.

I cant for the love of my life figure out why the addresses would be different!
I have made sure that the second time i call `Init()` with the same name that it does indeed open the file mapping successfully.

source: https://github.com/RavioliFinoli/SharedMemory

Comment: The more important question to me seems: if you use this shared memory, from within the same process, does the memory sharing work, despite the fact that the buffer addresses are different?

Comment: What is `pBuf`? What is `FileMapHandle`? How do you check the addresses? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? And why do you expect the returned address to be equal on each call?

Comment: And you *do* understand how [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) works? That you can have multiple addresses all mapped to the same physical memory?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, I suppose i did _not_ know how virtual memory works. The reason i was checking the `pBuf` pointers was that i tried adding and recieving data from the buffer but got garbage, but I guess the problem lies elsewhere.
I was under the impression that the pointer returned by `MapViewOfFile` would be pointing to the physical memory where the buffer lies, which is why I thought something was wrong when the pointers were different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is there a way i can verify that these adresses are mapped to the same physical memory?

Comment: Write to the memory using one of the pointers, then check the contents using the others?

Comment: Had to hardcode it since something else was obviously wrong in my implementation but yes, they point to the same physical memory.
Thank you, I'm studying game dev so some of these concept arent really taught in school. Im sure this is first-year knowledge to most data-scientists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping the same region twice in your process. You will get two distinct addresses, but they are backed by the same physical memory. Writing into the buffer pointed by the first address modifies the buffer pointed to by the second address, since they are really the same memory.